# what things I should have in header section of HTML website

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

I am learning how to create HTML website. I want to know what things (like meta, link, script etc) I should include in head section of the website ?

Please tell me all possible things which I should include with their descriptions.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we create a HTML page, we need to include the following in head section:

Link: Its a cascading style sheet which we use to create our page as per our design requirement.

JavaScript: It contains the javascript code for our functionality to perform client side operations.

Meta tags: Various the meta tags we have to include like "charset,viewport,description,keywords,Author,ROBOTS,googlebot,YahooSeeker,msnbot,reply-to etc.." along with canonical reference, go through the below link to understand all useful Meta tags that we have to use in our HTML page.

https://gist.github.com/kevinSuttle/1997924

Basic Meta Tags used for Search Engine Optimization.

Answer (score 0):

the most common tags are:

```
    <title>your websites title here</title>
    <style>your css here </style>
    <base href="http://www.your-base-default-url" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-external-css-file.css">
    <script>your javascript here if you have any</script>
    <meta name="choose-meta-tag-name" content="choose-meta-tag-content">
```

there are many types of meta tags, lookup here the ones you want you want to use
https://www.sitepoint.com/meta-tags-html-basics-best-practices/